# Mailgun Talon: Signature extraction example throwing error

Tags: mailgun

I installed mailgun/talon on GCE and was trying out the example in the README section, but it threw the following error at me:

```
>>> from talon import signature
>>> message = """Thanks Sasha, I can't go any higher and is why I limited it to the
... homepage.
... 
... John Doe
... via mobile"""
>>> message
"Thanks Sasha, I can't go any higher and is why I limited it to the\nhomepage.\n\nJohn     Doe\nvia mobile"
>>> text,signtr = signature.extract(message, sender='john.doe@example.com')
ERROR:talon.signature.extraction:ERROR when extracting signature with classifiers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "talon/signature/extraction.py", line 57, in extract
    markers = _mark_lines(lines, sender)
  File "talon/signature/extraction.py", line 99, in _mark_lines
    elif is_signature_line(line, sender, EXTRACTOR):
  File "talon/signature/extraction.py", line 40, in is_signature_line
    return classifier.decisionFunc(data, 0) > 0
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decisionFunc'
```

Do I need to train the model somehow (this signature seems to be the ML example)? I installed it using pip.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use signature parsing with classifiers you just need to call talon.init() before using the lib - it loads trained classifiers. Other methods like talon.signature.bruteforce.extract_signature() or talon.quotations.extract_from() don't require classifiers. Here's a full code sample:

```
import talon
# don't forget to init the library first
# it loads machine learning classifiers
talon.init()

from talon import signature


message = """Thanks Sasha, I can't go any higher and is why I limited it to the
homepage.

John Doe
via mobile"""

text, signature = signature.extract(message, sender='john.doe@example.com')
# text == "Thanks Sasha, I can't go any higher and is why I limited it to the\nhomepage."
# signature == "John Doe\nvia mobile"
```

Comment: Sergey, thanks for the help...one question, when I changed the sender to jdoe@example.com, it was not able to guess the signature...its a pretty common occurrence among email addrs (firstnamefirstletter-lastname@example.com), does that need me to initialize more complex models? I'm wondering about the difference between this ML approach and having some simple heuristics matching on things like (firstname,lastname etc). Thanks!

Comment: Heuristics could be very effective. We actually use heuristics first and than fallback to ML. You might want to look into talon.signature.bruteforce for some heuristics.At the moment talon doesn't use firstname / lastname as a simple heuristic but it's one of the features / checks in ML. We found it one of the most effective checks.

Comment: The problem with simple checks is that it's easy to overlook common edge cases. Currently first / last name is extracted from email address. It'd be great to improve the logic. Like your sample: stripping first letter and searching for (part of) lastname could yield good results.